# What formula is used by PIL to convert greyscale to RGB?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, grayscale

I have a greyscale image that, as a numpy array, has a maximal value of 91, but if it is first converted from grayscale to RGB, its maximal value (across all channels) is 255. What formula is being used here? When viewing the images using im.show() they look identical. I checked the PIL source code for 'convert' ([link](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/9e3ad5e9971fc0ec300e181ef014a6f467572b2d/src/PIL/Image.py#L851)) but it doesn't explicitly state how a greyscale image is converted to RGB.

I run the following:

```
im = PIL.Image.open(path_to_greyscale_image)
im_max_grey = max(np.asarray(im).flatten())
im = im.convert('RGB')
im_max_rgb = max(np.asarray(im).flatten())
```

Comment: Apparently the values are just scaled to the range 0-255 (8 bits per channel).

Comment: You can use `RGB = Image.merge('RGB', (grey,grey,grey))` to merge 3 identical copies of the grey channel, if that suits you better.

Comment: what is output look like? I don't think it is really colored. It just copies the same channel 3 times.

Comment: Your link say the methods. No formula. They just uses palette (the old method, when we had just 256 colours): you define in a table 256 colours, and in image you have just the index of such colours. You may want to look of old 256-palette or old 128-palette (for a specific system), or just choose yourself the palette. 91 colours are not too much to do manually.